# hsqldb data exception: string data, right truncation in statement

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, hsqldb

Email table was created using following command and currently it has around ~15000 records.

```
Create table emails (id INTEGER, accountid INTEGER, subject varchar(4000), 
sender varchar(100), sentDate TIMESTAMP, status varchar(10))
```

Now I am trying to add primary key on this table. For this purpose I am executing

```
ALTER TABLE emails ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

But this action is resulting into

```
data exception: string data, right truncation in statement [ALTER TABLE emails ADD 
PRIMARY KEY (ID)]
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is every `id` in your table unique, or could there be duplicates present?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes. There is a sequence for that.

Comment: Do you understand that trying to make a non unique column a primary key can cause problems?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Yes. I checked using GROUP BY clause to confirm no ID is repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in some rows one of the VARCHAR columns contains data that is longer than the declared size of the column.

You need to use a SELECT to find the longest strings and change the table definition with longer column definitions where necessary. For example:

```
SELECT MAX (CHAR_LENGTH(status)) FROM emails

ALTER TABLE emails ALTER COLUMN status SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. Why it allows to insert data which is longer that declared size?

Comment: You need to report the version of HSQLDB and how you insert the data.